# Intuition for microlinearity / infinitesimal linearity?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, synthetic-differential-geometry

In his books *Synthetic Differential Geometry* and *Synthetic Geometry of Manifolds*, Anders Kock defines a *microlinear space*, or an *infinitesimally linear space* $M$ as one with the following property.

**Microlinearity.** For each $n\geq 1$ and each $n$-tuple of maps $t_i:D\rightarrow M$ satisfying $t_i(0)=t_j(0)$ there's a unique $\ell:D(n)\rightarrow M$ satisfying $\ell \circ \iota_i =t_i$.

Here $D= \left\{x\in R\mid x^2=0 \right\}$, $D(n)= \left\{ (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in R^n\mid x_i\cdot x_j=0\;\forall i,j \right\}$, and $\iota_i:d\mapsto (0,\dots, d,\dots ,0)$.

What is the geometric meaning of this condition? Can anyone shed light on it? I understand it's a condition on all $n$-tuples of tangent vectors with common basepoint, I just don't get what it's saying. [This MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667352/geometric-meaning-of-d-kn-left-x-1-dots-x-n-in-rn-mid-prod-k-1k) is also related.

Comment: if you didn't understand after reading the book, it means that maybe the book is not so good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more-or-less saying that any $n$ tangent vectors span an infinitesimal linear space. In other words, it's a smoothness condition. For example, given $x, y : D \to M$ such that $x (0) = y (0)$, we get $z : D (2) \to M$ such that $z (d, 0) = x (d)$ and $z (0, d) = y (d)$; but for any $(\lambda, \mu) \in R^2$, we also have $\lambda x + \mu y : D \to M$ given by $d \mapsto z (\lambda d, \mu d)$. The uniqueness condition ensures that this is all well defined and gives the tangent space an $R$-module structure.

For comparison, consider a non-smooth space such as the union of the two coordinate axes in the plane. In that case, you can pick two linearly independent (... in some sense ...) tangent vectors at the origin, but we can't "linearly interpolate" between them.

Comment: Sorry for the trivial question, I'm still confused. Why do we have $\lambda x + \mu y : D \to M$ given by $d \mapsto z (\lambda d, \mu d)$ and how does the uniqueness show this is well defined? What well definedness is there to check?

Comment: Well, you have to check that it does not depend on $z$, for one thing, and then you have to check all the equations...

Comment: But where do we see any $n$ tangent vector generate a space of "full dimension"? Where is "linear independence" hiding?

Comment: Linear independence is not guaranteed. After all, $n$ can be arbitrarily large.